# socket.io - receive emit events from dynamically created namespace

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm trying to emit messages from my react client to my express server with socket.io.
Simplified Client:

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";

const Generator = () => {
    const socket = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.current = io("/something dynamic");
        socket.current.on('connect', () => { console.log('received connect') });

    }, [])
     
    const onStart = () => {
        socket.current.emit("start");
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={onStart}>Start</button>
    )
}
```

On the server I have:

```js
// socketClient.js
const io = require("socket.io")();

const workspaces = io.of(/^\/\w+$/);

workspaces.on('connect', socket => {
  const workspace = socket.nsp;
  console.log('socket connected');
  workspace.on('start', data => {
    console.log('received start')
  })
});

module.exports = io;

// server/bin/www
const io = require('./socketClient');
// ... server definitions etc from default express generator
io.attach(server)
```

Both the client and server recognize the `connect` event and log to console accordingly. However, when click the button to emit the `start` event, the server never gets it and I have no idea why.

The goal is to create a distinct namespace & socket connection per-user so that there is no overlap. I'm using sockets to provide realtime progress updates for some long-running API calls and computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need dynamic namespaces:

```js
// socketClient.js
const nsp = io.of('/csv');
nsp.on('connection', async socket => {
  // Now I can use socket.on for any events I need
  socket.on("start", async (data) => {
    // Do start stuff
  }
});
```

Each connection is unique and I can avoid emitting globally by avoiding `broadcast` or `io.sockets.emit`